# Trouble with playing/displaying MP4 Video

Tags: html, wordpress, video

I have trouble adding an MP4 Video to my website.
The link to my site is http://san-kelloff-italy.com/

The code I'm using:

```
<video width = "320" height = "240" controls autoplay>
   <source src = "http://san-kelloff-italy.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/video_sk.MP4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

On Chrome the videos does't play.

On FireFox the videos said **"No video with supported format and MIME type found."**

I'm not sure what's going on but when I tried the code using this link below the videos can play on both chrome and firefox

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_video_html5

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding FireFox, MP4 is not (usually) supported. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats for documentation.

Edit: The OGG format is used as a secondary format to allow for cross-browser playback. That's why the link you posted contained two references: one to the MP4 and another to the OGG.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support video
</video>
```

MP4s (and a few other patented codecs) will work on FireFox if the underlying OS or hardware has and shares the decoder. Opera also doesn't support MP4 and I can't find evidence that they  will use the OS's decoder if available.

Comment: Hey, I have seen some document said that Firefox doesn't support mp4 but when I tested on the w3schools with my block of code the videos still play normally...it just doesn't play on my website. Does it have to do with my website htaccess file?

Comment: Your block of code does not work for me on the w3schools site in FireFox. I very much doubt it has anything to do with the htaccess file. I suggest converting the video to OGG (there are free tools like this one: http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg) and giving it a try.

Comment: Hey. I got it done! Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Cool, glad that's working. I still suggest having an OGG as backup. FireFox relies on the OS or hardware to supply MP4 support, so it will only work as long as the OS or hardware on users' machines have and allow FF to use the decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was being clumsy and careless to make this mistake.
I have figured out how to fixed it.

What I did was I renamed the .MP4 on my file to lowercase and also changed the link location on the code block

FROM.

```
<video width = "320" height = "240" controls autoplay>
   <source src = "http://san-kelloff-italy.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/video_sk.MP4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

To.

```
<video width = "320" height = "240" controls autoplay>
   <source src = "http://san-kelloff-italy.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/video_sk.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

So just other people who is like me being careless about the links and think that it is not case sensitive which it is! So be careful!